# Graphhopper access restriction

Tags: graphhopper

Graphhopper obeys access restrictions like gates with attribute "access = no" (OSM). But additional attributes like "bicycle = yes" are ignored.

Question: is it possible to tell Graphhopper to pass a gate when bikes are allowed and routing is optimized for bicycles?

Comment: `bicycle = yes` should not be ignored. Do you have an example? Is it  a gate on a node?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Page http://graphhopper.com/maps/ has been updated. Now I can choose between "bike" and "bike2". Both work fine. Only if I choose "foot" I am blocked by a gate and Graphhopper suggests detour.